# How to check from within a Rust function if it is called directly or by Invoke() from C# code?

Tags: reflection, rust, ffi

I am calling a Rust function in a native DLL from C# like this:

```cs
[DLLImport("rust.dll")]
public static int Foo(int i);
public static void Invoke() {
    typeof(Program).GetMethod("Foo").Invoke(new object[] {null}, new object[] {1});
}
public static void Call() {
    Foo(1);
}
```

I want to check if a the method is called directly or by using `Invoke`. If it's invoked the method should print `"Invoked"`, if not it should print `"Called"`. I'm not really sure if you can differentiate between these two things.

Comment: What the difference between called and invoked for you ?

Comment: called is like: foo(); invoked is invoke by using reflections xD

Comment: There is no reflection like this in Rust.

Comment: like calling a rust fn with p/invoke in .NET and invoking the rust fn with reflections in .NET

Comment: There is no difference from the point of view of a function in rust, both call it. Better question why do you need to know ?

Comment: Please add example code which demonstrates calling a function vs and invoking it, to help explain what you mean by these terms (to me, they are the same, but obviously you have something in mind about how they are different).

Comment: Also read [mcve], which gives some good advice to new users on how to ask questions that are easy for others to answer.

Comment: i have added an example

Comment: Would you be able to detect this if the DLL was written in C, rather than Rust? If so, then use the same interface from Rust. However, I don't think .Net exposes that information in any reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible, without doing something very weird, which definitely would not portable, futureproof or in any way robust.

From inside Rust, a function call is a function call, no matter which foreign API was used to call it.

Comment: Always be careful when giving a negative answer. You could get this information from the call stack for example. No saying it is a good idea. Not saying it would be reliable. But it could work.